# Change background colour of dropdownlist selected item in ASP.NET with CSS

Tags: c#, asp.net, css

I would like to change the background colour of the selected item in dropdownlists, listboxes, and textboxes. Is this possible with CSS?

Thanks

**UPDATE**

Just tried this CSS:

```
::-moz-selection 
{
    background-color:#8CCA1E;
    color:Black;
}
```

Works great for selected text but not for hover colours or selected item colours on dropdownlists or listboxes.

Comment: You're going to have compatibility issues with -moz-selection.  IE6 doesn't support it, can't speak to IE7 or IE8, but I suspect that 7 at least doesn't

Comment: @James B - that's Ok I am only using Firefox within an intranet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set background colors from the .aspx page by specifying either the CssClass, or the BackColor property.. it looks like:

```
<asp:ListBox CssClass="MyListBox" BackColor="#e0e0e0"></asp:ListBox>
```

Setting the selected item is a little trickier... I don't believe there is an attribute for this directly.  You can set it in javascript, or jQuery, something like:

```
// Never mind, this won't work
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#MyListBox').click(function() {
        $("#MyListBox option:selected").css("background-color", "#e0e0e0");
    }); 
  });
</script>
```

I'll test that to make sure it works... if you need a straight javascript solution, I'll see what I can come up with.  But if you're not using jQuery, and you want fine-grained control over your controls, now is a good time to learn it : )

Thanks to Justin for corrections to the script!

**EDIT**
Hover is easy... add a style:

```
  select > option:hover {
    background-color:  #ffffd0;
  }
```

That will set the background color on any listbox item you hover over on the page.  jQuery can be used to set the click function on all listboxes, not just specifically #MyListBox... give me a couple of minutes, I'll add some code

**UPDATE**
After extensive research, exhausting every resource I had or can put my hands on, the best answer I come up with is:  Setting the selected color can't be done.

Not even the jQuery code I came up with will work.  The selected color is set by the OS, and can't be overridden.

Sorry, best I can do is the :hover pseudo-selector
: (

.

Comment: I am using jQuery and I have lots of dropdowns on my web form. Is there a way to apply a hover colour and selected colour to all of them? I don't want to set the background colour, just the hover and selected colours with jQuery. Thanks!

Comment: Most **IMPORTANT** part to read here and I'm starting to see over and over is this comment: _Not even the jQuery code I came up with will work. The selected color is set by the OS, and can't be overridden._ I see a lot of posts where folks rattle off `jQuery` snippets to change the CSS but never test it. Thus far I can change the backcolor of non-selected elements, but the selected color is not overrideable.

Answer (score 0):

You could create CSS rules for this and apply them programmatically in the change handlers in your code. Or you could tap into the System.Drawing namespace to achieve the same thing in your handlers.

```
// CSS 
.dropDownBackColor { background-color:#00ff00; }

// Code-Behind: in your selected index changed event handler 
// for the drop down list
ddl.CssClass = "dropDownBackColor";
```

OR

```
ddl.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;
```

Comment: won't this just change the background colour of the dropdown? I'm only interested in changing the hover colour and the selected colour. Is there a way to do that programmatically?

Comment: Then I think that jQuery would be the way to go for both :-)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is using JS..

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" onchange="SelectedItemCLR(this);">  
   <asp:ListItem Text="Name1" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>  
   <asp:ListItem Text="Name2" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>  
   <asp:ListItem Text="Name3" Value="3"></asp:ListItem>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">  
  function SelectedItemCLR(source) {   

      for (var i = 0; i < source.options.length; i++) {   
        if (i != source.selectedIndex)   
              source.options[i].style.backgroundColor = "White";   
          else   
              source.options[i].style.backgroundColor = "Red"; 

      }   
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I would like the colours to be defined in my CSS file - is there a way to do that with JS? I don't want the colours hard-coded in my asp pages.

Comment: I think you can specify CSS class, like this..     source.options[i].className ="YourCSS Name";

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try out the css selector ::selection which sounds like it will do what you want.  [Here's](http://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/) a good article on it.  The only problem is it seems to be css3 only, so you may want to try the jquery solution James B posted, depending on what your browser requirements are.

Comment: Cool, I am using a modern browser and don't need to worry about supporting older browsers. So, a CSS3 solution would be perfect. I have tried this using the code updated in my question, however the hover colours in dropdowns and listboxes are not changed. Selected text works fine though. Do you know how to change the colour of hover colours and selected items in dropdownlists and listboxes?

Comment: Well it looks like Chrome works the same way as firefox http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=62263.  Also did you happen to try input ::moz-selection for your selector??

Comment: I'm afraid that James B might be right, I can't think of a way to do this either.