# Change highlighted color of item selected Listbox Control of Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox

How can i change with CSS and not codebehind c# the APS.NET ListBox selected item background color when selected? I wanna change the blue color into grey. How can i do it?

[image: Change Color]

Thanks

Comment: Check out this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4185564/change-background-colour-of-dropdownlist-selected-item-in-asp-net-with-css

Comment: It says : Not even the jQuery code I came up with will work. The selected color is set by the OS, and can't be overridden..... with css too?